# How to create template suggestion for image like IMAGE--BLOCK-TYPE or IMAGE--FIELD-TYPE

Tags: 8, theming

I'm struggling to make template suggestions like IMAGE--BLOCK-TYPE or IMAGE--FIELD-TYPE.
I have three different block types(image1, image2, image3) with one image field(field_image_1, field_image_2 and field_image_3).
And I don't know how to get suggestion like

```
image--block_image1.html.twig
image--block_image2.html.twig
image--block_image3.html.twig
```

or

```
image--field_image_1.html.twig
image--field_image_2.html.twig
image--field_image_3.html.twig
```

Is there any way to pass variable between the two hooks below?

```
  function full_nature_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

    global $block_id;

    $block_id = $variables['elements']['#id'];

  }
```

and

```
  function full_nature_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

    $suggestions[] = 'image__'.$block_id;

  }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2021-02-23/how-to-create-template-suggestion-for-image-like-image#comment-14017195

It is alternative solution but it works with this module

https://www.drupal.org/project/image_class

Answer (score 0):

This is right solution but it works only with this module https://www.drupal.org/project/image_class

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */

function full_nature_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $image = $variables['attributes']['class'][0];
  $suggestions[] = 'image__'.$image;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put both your answers into one, highlight the code and summarize the forum post you are referring to? Many thanks